# How do I serialize a C# 'single case union type'-like object to its underlying value and back?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am modeling a domain, and for a select few properties, even though their values are simple, I don't want to use a built-in integral (e.g. `int`) or a very general type (e.g. `System.Guid`).

So I introduced some simple 'wrapper' types. Combined with implicit operators I am happy with the result:

```
class Order
{
    public Price Price { get; set; }
}

order.Price = 4.95m;
```

Where `Price` 'wraps' `decimal` and stores the value in a private field named `value`.

I am now serializing objects to JSON, and I would like the object above to be serialized like this:

```
{
    "Price": 4.95
}
```

But so far I have only been able to serialize it like this, by making the field a public property:

```
{
    "Price": {
        "Value": 4.95
    }
}
```

Do you know of a way (preferably with NewtonSoft.Json) to serialize, and deserialize, in the way I described?

Comment: A custom converter for the `Price` class and use `JsonSerializerSettings` (add the converter to the `Converters` list) when (de)serialising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a custom converter. For example:

```
public class PriceConverter : JsonConverter<Price>
{
    public override Price ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Price existingValue, 
        bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.Value);
        return new Price { Value = value };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Price value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.Value);
    }
}
```

Now you just need to tell JSON.Net to use the converter. One way is to add it to your serialiser settings:

```
//Create the settings object and add the converter
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new PriceConverter());

//Use the settings
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order, settings);
var newOrder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(json, settings);
```

Alternatively, use an attribute to tell JSON.Net which converter to use, either on the property:

```
public class Order
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PriceConverter))]
    public Price Price { get; set; }
}
```

Or on the class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(PriceConverter))]
public class Price 
{
    public decimal Value { get; set; }  
}
```